# Biggest set of vertices such that any shortest path is "independent"

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E) $ be a graph. We want to find the largest set $I \subset V$ such that for any $u,v \in I$ we have that the shortest path between $u,v$ in $G$ does not contain any of the other vertices in $I$.

I guess that this has to be a known problem but I haven't figured out a way to solve it. As a trivial example I guess that in a tree the answer would be all the leaves.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: The shortest path is not necessarily unique. Do you want there to be *some* shortest $u,v$-path not containing any other vertex in $I$, or do you want this to be true for *every* shortest path?

Comment: @MishaLavrov True, I think the second case sounds kind of more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem is NP-hard: there is a reduction from the maximum-clique problem.

Given an $n$-vertex graph $G$, let $H$ be the graph extending $G$ by adding a set $S$ of $n+1$ vertices adjacent to every vertex in $G$, and to each other. Let $I$ be a largest shortest-path-independent set in $H$.

Any clique is shortest-path-independent, because any two vertices in a clique have a unique shortest path of length $1$. In particular, $S$ is shortest-path-independent, so $|I| \ge |S| = n+1$, which means $|I \cap S| \ge 1$.

As a result, $I$ must be a clique in $H$: if two vertices $v,w \in I$ are not adjacent, and $u \in I \cap S$, then $(v,u,w)$ is a shortest $v,w$-path that contains another vertex in $I$. So $I$ is just a maximum clique in $H$, and $I \cap V(G)$ is a maximum clique in $G$.